# WPF image Stream

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have this program which shows camera stream and when click on button capture image in stream. What I am trying to do is to flush the earlier image when I click on capture button again. 
here is the program

```
    public static void SaveImageCapture(BitmapSource bitmap)
    {
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
        encoder.QualityLevel = 100      
        FileStream fstream = new FileStream("new_n.jpg", FileMode.Create);
        encoder.Save(fstream);
        fstream.Close();
    }
```

this saved file is passed to some other routine.  
Doesn't fstream.close() flush it automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

Your safest bet is to put the stream part in a using statement:

```
using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream("new_n.jpg", FileMode.Create))
{
    encoder.Save(fstream);
}
```

Comment: if instead of saving image if i just use bitmapsource as input would that solve the problem , means it wont save anything and i need picture only for analysis and then discard.  I am a beginner to WPF.

Comment: Maybe, but it's difficult to understand exactly what your problem is. Maybe you could elaborate?